# Polynomial subspace

Tags: vector-spaces

Wondering abut this set : $E=(p(X) \ \in \mathbb{R}[X]; Xp(X)+p'(X)=0)$, is it a subspace of $\mathbb{R}[X] $?

I definitely think it is because it only includes the zero polynomial but how could we prove it ? I usually take $u$ and $v$ which are in the set and then prove that $\lambda u+v \ \in$ the set but don't see how to proceed  here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already see that the set only includes the zero polynomial, then all you need to do is, as always, prove that if $u,v\in E$, then so is $\lambda u +v \in E$. There's nothing special that requires you to change the definition you're using - however, if $u,v\in E$ and $E$ contains only the zero polynomial, then $u=v= 0$ meaning $\lambda u + v=0$ and since $0\in E$, we get $\lambda u + v \in E$ for any choice of $u$, $v$, or $\lambda$.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to solve it, just verify linearity:

$\qquad p' = -xp,\, q' = -xq\,\Rightarrow\, (c_1 p+c_2 q)' = c_1 p' + c_2 q' = -x(c_1 p + c_2q)$

Equivalently $\ X + d/dx$ is a linear operator, being the sum of linear operators, and your set is its kernel.

Answer (score 1):

The map $\phi:\mathbb{R}[X]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}[X]$ such that $\phi(P)(X)=XP(X)+P'(X)$ is linear. $E=\ker\phi$ and therefore is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}[X]$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Find all elements of the set $E$.

> **Hint 2:** Look at the degrees and leading coefficients.